# Chrome background Extension - using chrome flags (like --disable-web-security)

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension, applet

We have an Chrome Background Extension that loads on the windows startup.
the plugin create an iframe element and load Java Applet that will be used later
(techniqe to keep the JVM loaded and reduce the applet loading time).

the problem is that the first instance of the chrome.exe is running without any custom flags like --disable-web-security and  --allow-outdated-plugins .

so the background task cannot perfrom well.

is there any setting we can use in the registry or chrome plugin API that can be used.

we deploying this Extension in the internal ENV , and the browser dont have any direct internet access.

10x
elad.

Comment: found it :-)  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AdditionalLaunchParameters"="--enable-media-stream --enable-media-source"

Comment: Better add this as an answer and accept it (this will help people know this question has an answer and find it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it :-) [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome] "AdditionalLaunchParameters"="--enable-media-stream --enable-media-source"